# Node-Red flow deploy using http request

Tags: ibm-watson, node-red, watson

I am referring this example https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/node-red-labs/tree/master/starter-kits/ok_watson and could successfully deploy it in Node-Red. But in this sample the input is Inject based. Is there a way of deploying this same example onto a page using HTTP request or maybe Websocket? I figured we can use http request and response for that, but how should the template code look like if i need microphone and audio out in my http webpage. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is. The flows require a text input, which could easily come from a HTTP form. So add a HTTP Input, HTTP Response and Template with a form, and you should have your text input.

Comment: I am struggling with how the Template HTML code should be? :(

Comment: The basic pattern for a template form, that invokes a HTTP Request as a REST call can be found at this link - https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/node-red-labs/blob/master/basic_examples/conversation/conversation_lab.json You need to wrap the HTTP Rest call bit around your ok-watson flow.

Comment: Thanks, I did went through this sample. Here i am not very sure what the response id is, so i can experiment a little with it.